# onEdit updates top row only after editing multiple rows, but not after copy paste

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google script that when user edit the cell in the spreadsheet, then there will be a current date automatically show up on the right cell.

my script is:

```
function onEdit(edit) {

var row = edit.range.getRow();
var col = edit.range.getColumn();

if(col === 32 && edit.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Sheet A")
  edit.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,33).setValue(new Date());

if(col === 32 && edit.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Sheet B")
  edit.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,33).setValue(new Date());

}
```

The date only shows if the user edits the cell. But, **what I expect is**, whenever the user edits the cell **OR copy-paste the cell to other cells in the same column; then the date is also automatically shown on the right column.**

Does anyone know how should I solve this?

Comment: consider using e.range.rowStart and e.range.rowEnd

Answer (score 0):

The edit event source is referencing the cell that changed value in column 32 and your code does that correctly. If you are expecting the date to update in column 33 to the right of the cell that you copy from it doesn't because the value did not change it was copied.

Comment: Yes yes, so do you how I should change my script so that not only when user edit the column 32, but also by copy-paste cells in column 32; the date will automatically updated on column 33. What script that I should adjust?